# String to DateTime conversion substracts 1 hour from initial time

Tags: php, datetime

```
$initialTime = "31.03.2015 17:59";
$timeStamp = (new IntlDateFormatter('en_US', IntlDateFormatter::SHORT, IntlDateFormatter::SHORT, 'Europe/Moscow', IntlDateFormatter::GREGORIAN,'dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm'))->parse($initialTime);
$dt = new DateTime('@'.$timeStamp.' UTC');
$dt->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Europe/Moscow')); 
var_dump($dt);
```

So, from `$initialTime` I'm getting `$timeStamp` by using `IntlDateFormatter::parse()` (Timezone is `'Europe/Moscow'`)

Then I parse `$timeStamp` to `DateTime` and set its timezone to the same, but it outputs:

```
class DateTime#1 (3) {
  public $date =>
  string(19) "2015-03-31 16:59:00"
  public $timezone_type =>
  int(3)
  public $timezone =>
  string(13) "Europe/Moscow"
}
```

Why is the initial time different from the output time by one hour?

Comment: the first operation is not setting the system time, the class means International Date Formatter = IntlDateFormatter

Comment: Yes it's not. Sorry for my English, but problem with missing hour still exist.
At the notice, it is code from `\Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\DataTransformer\DateTimeToLocalizedStringTransformer::reverseTransform()`.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like something wrond with `IntlDateFormatter`. `Timestamp` from `DateTime` object differs from parsed one.

```
$initialDate = new DateTime();
$initialDate->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone('Europe/Moscow'));
$initialTime =$initialDate->format('d.m.Y H:i');
echo $initialTime, "\n";
echo "Real timestamp: ", $initialDate->getTimestamp(), "\n";
$timeStamp = (new IntlDateFormatter('ru_RU', IntlDateFormatter::SHORT, IntlDateFormatter::SHORT, 'Europe/Moscow', IntlDateFormatter::GREGORIAN,'dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm'))->parse($initialTime);
echo "Parsed timestamp: ", $timeStamp, "\n";
```

output:

```
01.04.2015 16:39
Real timestamp:   1427895596
Parsed timestamp: 1427891940
```